# How do Bitcoin exchanges fill orders?

Tags: exchanges, exchange-order

If the order book looks like the following…

```
A)  Ask: 2 bitcoin at $100

B)  Bid: 2 bitcoin at $100
```

A trade will be done from A to B.

But what happens in the following situation:

```
C)  Ask: 1 bitcoin $100

D)  Bid: 2 bitcoin $100
```

**Do bitcoin exchanges partially fill orders?**

Does one of the following occur:

- Nothing the orders need to be the same quantity.
- Does the trade occur for one bitcoin.
- If the trade does occur, what happens if the bid is cancelled? Is the trade for 1 bitcoin still valid.

Also, what happens in this situation:

```
E)  Ask:2 bitcoin $90

F)  Bid: 2 bitcoin $100
```

**Does the Bid pay $100 or $90?**

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Yes, orders will be partially filled. Some exchanges offer advanced orders that can only be completed wholly, but that's not the default.

Q2: The deciding price is the one that entered the book first. So if first a $90 ask is placed and then a $100 bid is placed, the trade will be executed at $90.